# Facebook app restricted on iPad

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've created my first Facebook app at https://apps.facebook.com/splatanimate and it works fine in a PC browser but when I attempt to use it in the iPad Facebook app, it says "Use of app "Splatanimate" has been restricted" [Try Again] [Find another app]

I have checked that I have no application restrictons on in the app's Advanced Settings (e.g. age, alcohol) and there are no parental restrictions on the iPad.

Any ideas much appreciated!(or even tips on how to diagnose the problem).

Many Thanks

Comment: Have you set up a Mobile Site URL in your App's settings?

Comment: Yes...same as my main site url

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer from the Facebook app developers group - turned out to be a bug in Facebook itself which they have now fixed for my app.